# ANTLR: Automatic Error Recovery doesn't seem to work

Tags: antlr, recovery

i have a problem with the automatic error recovery of ANTLR v3 which doesn't seem to work in my grammar. 
Consider following grammar:

```
grammar test;

parse   :   define*;

define  :   LPAREN 'define' VARIABLE RPAREN;

// Tokens
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';

LETTER  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');

VARIABLE : LETTER*;

SPACE : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

when i call the parse-rule with following input:

```
(define alpha)
(define beta)
```

he successfully parses both define-rules.
however, when i enter a token which doesn't fit:

```
(define alpha)
)
(define beta)
```

he cancels parsing on the first sight of the misplaced RPAREN token. I thought that antlr could handle misplaced tokens and tries to return to a rule, but it doesn't seem to work for me. What am i doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you call the `parse` rule:

```
parse : define*;
```

the parser tries to match as many `define` rules as possible for the input:

```
(define alpha)
)
(define beta)
```

After it successfully matches `(define alpha)`, it then sees a `)`, so it can't match a `define` rule anymore and stops parsing therefor. And because `)` *is* a valid token in your lexer grammar, you see no warning or error.

You'll need to tell your parser to go through the *entire* token stream by "anchoring" your main parser rule by placing the `EOF` (end-of-file) token at the end:

```
parse : define* EOF;
```

If you now parse the input again, you will see the following error on your console:

```
line 2:0 missing EOF at ')'
```

#### EDIT

The fact that `define*` does not recover is probably because there is no fixed amount of tokens, making the recovery process too hard. The following demo seems to confirm my suspicion:

```
grammar test;

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source =  
        "(define alpha) \n" +
        ")              \n" +
        "(define beta)    ";
    testLexer lexer = new testLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    testParser parser = new testParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}

parse    : define define EOF {System.out.println("parsed >>>" + $text + "<<<");};
define   : LPAREN 'define' VARIABLE RPAREN;
LPAREN   : '(';
RPAREN   : ')';
LETTER   : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');
VARIABLE : LETTER+;
SPACE    : (' ' | '\n' | '\t' | '\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

If you run the `testParser` class, the following is printed to the console:

```
line 2:0 extraneous input ')' expecting LPAREN
parsed >>>(define alpha) 
)              
(define beta)    <<<
```

I.e., the warning *is* printed to the `System.err`, but the parsing also continues when limiting the `parse` rule to two `define`'s instead of `define*`.

Comment: @ Bart: i understand that, but then again he doesn't parse the second expression. How do i make antlr to try the "recovery by single symbol deletion" like it is described in TP's Antlr book?

Comment: this is really unfortunate for me. how is this so different to the examples in the book or other situations where the error recovery works?

Comment: no it has the same error. But i tried out the grammar from the book and it seems to only recover when it expected fixed tokens (like `;`) , not rule or subrules, just like you said. Thank you anyway. I will post this on the ANTLR mailinglist to see if someone knows a solution, but i think you are right.

Comment: @Sebastian, correct, the error still appears (because it's still wrong), but the parse _does_ continue. See my **EDIT** .